# Jenkins connected to bitBucket but refuses to clone

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

Trying to access a bitbucket server (in local network) from Jenkins (also locally installed). The BitBucket version is v5.11.
I've followed the instructions here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/ssh-access-keys-for-system-use-776639781.html

which seems to describe the use case I want to setup.

What I've done:

- Registered SSH public key as a Project access key into bitbucket. And
  added the corresponding private key into Jenkins.
- With Jenkin's BitBucket plugin, registered the bitbucket server in
  "Manage Jenkins"-> "Configure System" -> "Bitbucket Server
  Integration". With this, test connection works with message `Jenkins can connect with Bitbucket Server.` displayed.
- Then in Jenkins project's "Source Code Management", selected 'Bitbucket Server' and filled in the required fields. 'Test connection' here also works with displayed message: `Jenkins successfully connected to BitBucket's <Project> / <Repo> on Primary Server`.

All seem fine until I try to run the build. Seems Jenkins can't clone the repo from Bitbucket:

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\<userId>\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 8666a4bf-0ea1-466a-ab89-ea312f879ea0
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository ssh://git@<bitbucket_server_url>/path/to/repo.git
 > git.exe init C:\Users\<userId>\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo '<repo name>'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init C:\Users\<userId>\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:997)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:752)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1221)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1299)
    at com.atlassian.bitbucket.jenkins.internal.scm.BitbucketSCM.checkout(BitbucketSCM.java:207)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: git.exe init C:\Users\<userId>\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2457)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2380)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2376)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1923)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:995)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\C:\Users\<userId>\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:996)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:508)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2443)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:478)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:154)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 23 more
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'prism-v1.3.0.68'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any insight into what's causing the issue is much appreciated!

Comment: Hard for me to be sure, especially with the Windows stuff (I avoid Windows), but it sure looks like you simply don't have Git *installed* on the Jenkins build system. If you do have it installed, you may need to tell Jenkins *where* as it might be in some non-standard location, or perhaps that system does not have a single standard location for Git.

Comment: Ahh you are right.. that was dumb of me! /facepalm  I was fixating on whether they got security permissions to talk to each other, and it was staring at me in the stacktrace. Thanks again!